# Tensorflow - Seq2Seq model weights are not loaded properly

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, chatbot, seq2seq

I am working on an `encoder-decoder` chat bot that consists of an `embedding layer`, two layers of `LSTM` and a `fully connected layer` on top of the decoder.

After I load the `checkpoint file`, the `loss` is way higher than it was the last time I saved the model, and the results of the chat bot are, as expected, way worse. And yet, the model is not back at his initial state. Which means that if I saved the model when it had 2.4 loss, it will load on 4-5 loss instead of 10 (which is the loss the model had before it started learning).

Also, the model learns a lot faster after the weights have been loaded which leads me to believe that some of the weights have been loaded successfully while some have not.

I'm using this code to build the model and load the `checkpoint` in the `__init__` function:

```python
self.__gather_data()        
self.__build_model()    
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=self.sess)        
self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
try:
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.checkpoint_path)
except:
    print('Starting from scratch.')
```

This is how I build the model in the `__build_model` function:

```python
# placeholders
with tf.variable_scope(self.scope + '-placeholders'):       
    self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None, self.input_length], name='inputs')
    self.outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='outputs')
    self.targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='targets')   

# embedding
with tf.variable_scope(self.scope + 'embedding'):
    self.input_embedding = tf.Variable(tf.ones((self.vocab_size, self.embed_size)))
    self.output_embedding = tf.Variable(tf.ones((self.vocab_size, self.embed_size)))
    input_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.input_embedding, self.inputs)
    output_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.output_embedding, self.outputs)

# encoder
with tf.variable_scope(self.scope + '-encoder'):
    lstm_enc_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.hidden_size, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    lstm_enc_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.hidden_size, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    _, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[lstm_enc_1, lstm_enc_2]), inputs=input_embed, dtype=tf.float32)

# decoder
with tf.variable_scope(self.scope + '-decoder'):
    lstm_dec_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.hidden_size, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE) 
    lstm_dec_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.hidden_size, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE) 
    dec_outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[lstm_dec_1, lstm_dec_2]), inputs=output_embed, initial_state=last_state, dtype=tf.float32)            
    self.logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(dec_outputs, num_outputs=self.vocab_size, activation_fn=None, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, scope='fully_connected')

# loss and optimizer
with tf.variable_scope(self.scope + '-optimizing'):
    self.loss = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(self.logits, self.targets, tf.ones([self.batch_size, self.input_length]))
    self.optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001).minimize(self.loss)
```

And I'm using this function to save the weights while training:

```python
self.saver.save(self.sess, self.checkpoint_path)
```

Comment: Since the issue seems to be related with loading & saving your model, please include the relevant code (not sure if dumping the whole of your model is in any way useful - please see why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)).

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for pointing that out. I've made some changes, anything else?

Comment: OK, since you asked :)... put this before your first code snippet, in order to have syntax highlighting (which arguably makes your code more readable): `<!-- language-all: lang-python -->`